# How to stub @Asychronous annotation methods in Java with Mockito/ Powemockito testing framework with jUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am using Powermockito to unit test a **method** which calls to a private method which has @Asychronous annotation in Java. When i try to call that **method** on the mocked object, I get this error

"Attempt to execute asynchronous code outside of AsyncScope.doAsync() method"

Comment: Have you tried doing a `@PrepareForTest({ClassBeingTested.class})`? I did some searching but don't see an easy way to suppress the `@Asynchronous` annotation's behavior. Can you provide a code example?